# firebase admin multi-factor login

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-hosting

excited about Firebase, my admins must use multi-factor login for the account dashboard (policy issue).  Is this possible? Is it a setting I can't find?  Can I login to account dashboard using Google (and thus force mult-factor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I work for Firebase*

Firebase's log in system is separate from Google's and does not offer two-factor auth. We are looking to enhance this, but currently these are constraints.

If you want your application administrators to go through a more stringent log in process than Firebase allows for its account dashboard, you might want to consider setting up an application-administration dashboard. This is just a separate section of your application that you build. So that also means you have full control over the access mechanism, through a [custom token generator](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html).

Comment: Understood, thanks.  Custom tokens look very useful, for role based authorization, etc....   In this case, I have to certify that ALL admin access to the data is multi-factor.  Even with a separate app-dashboard the account dashboard still exists.

Can't work out issues for current project.  Next project, in October will be firebase from ground up.